# How to open cmd window and run commands in it with a batch file?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

**Main question:** I want to use a batch file to open cmd window so that some commands are run on that new opened window. How do I do that?

To be more precise I want to make batch file which would open a cmd window, compile Java code and run the application (using commands listed in the batch file) so I could see some application output in the window and when application closes cmd window should stay open. Saying this because I don't know if there are specific/useful use cases conserning Java.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in the [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Have your batch file call another batch file with `&` at the end. The second file will have to know to wait before closing.

ex:
file1.bat

```
echo "hi"
.\file2.bat &
echo "bye"
"read user input"
```

file2.bat

```
echo "hello"
"read user input"
```

Comment: I know I can run another batch within the first one but want to do everything in a single batch. If that is not possible I will have to stick with extra batch:/

Comment: If you want everything to run in the first what's the problem? If it's just that it closes too quickly, add a line at the end where you wait for the user to press a key.

Comment: if it would be one java command then I could do `cmd /k java app.AppMain` and the output would be satisfying (http://prntscr.com/ei1jjy) but I want to run two komands `javac -encoding UTF-8 app/AppMain.java java app.AppMain` so if I put them into the batch file ('cmd /k javac -encoding UTF-8 app/AppMain.java java app.AppMain') I get nothing. Don't know how to "pipe" two or more commands...

Comment: Do you mean you get nothing as in no cmd pops up?

Comment: cmd does pop up but not single Java command is being run so I guess there must be a specific syntax or something. Going afk, ty for trying to help!